# Variance of Univariate Gaussian Mixture

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, variance, borel-measures

Let $\mathbb{P}_1,\dots,\mathbb{P}_n$ be univariate Gaussian measures with respective means $m_1,\dots,m_n \in \mathbb{R}$ and respective variances $\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_n$.  Let $r_1,\dots,r_n$ be numbers in $(0,1)$ which sum to $1$.  Is the variance of a random variable distributed according to $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i\mathbb{P}_n$ equal to $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2 \sigma_i^2$?

Comment: What do you mean with "measures $m_1,...,m_n$"? Are $\mathbb{P}_1,\dots,\mathbb{P}_n$ indipendent or with $Cov(\mathbb{P}_i,\mathbb{P}_j)=0$?

Comment: Sorry those should be means (still the morning here)

Comment: How can measures be dependent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define indipendent random variable $X_i$ with distribution $\mathbb{P}_i$.
Thus $\mathbb{E}[X_i]=m_i$ and $Var(X_i)=\sigma_i^2$.

Finally note that $Var(\sum_{i=1}^n r_iX_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n Var(r_iX_i)$ because they are uncorrelated (they are independent) and then you get $\sum_{i=1}^n Var(r_iX_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n r_i^2 \sigma_i^2$ also if you do not assume $r_1,...,r_n$ have sum $1$.